# TFS Build fails with "Could not copy file" of file not even in the project

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have TFS Build set up, which worked fine until yesterday. Since then I get the following error from one project:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
>   (182): Could not copy the file
>   "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png" because it
>   was not found.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
>   (182): Could not copy the file
>   "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png" because
>   it was not found. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
>   (182): Could not copy the file
>   "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee_1x400.png" because
>   it was not found.
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
>   (182): Could not copy the file
>   "Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png" because
>   it was not found. C:\Program Files
>
> ...and about 10 more...

The files mentioned by the error are nowhere to be found, not in the project nor in any folder of the project.

**Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?**

At Ln 182 of the .target file is the following:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)" Condition="'%(Content.Link)' == ''"
DestinationFolder="$(WebProjectOutputDir)\%(Content.RelativeDir)" 
SkipUnchangedFiles="true" 
Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)" />
```

I also have a second project in the solution which is nearly the same and builds fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grep/Search the entire source tree for those filenames - something must be referencing them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that actually helped me solve it: As only my main project referenced that files, I did take another look at the build log and saw that I misread `Built $/PATH.csproj for default targets.` for `Building...` -> I searched the error in the wrong project -> the files where somehow removed from TFS -> readded them from the local verisons -> working again.

Comment: @chrfin, I didn't understand how you did it. Facing same issue.

Comment: @Shimmy: First: Read the build log again ;-) (this was my first problem, as I misread it the first time) 2) Search the whole solution for references to the files in question 3) Remove the references or readd the files

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=F6Jr5XQe)'s the log file. I'm using TFS Build to deploy to a Windows Azure server. I tried deleting all those files and readding them to my project, however build still fails

Comment: Do the files lsited as "not found" exist on the build server?

Comment: I have the files in source control and I need them. The solution of remove the references to those files is not applicable to my situation. I don't get why I am facing this error :(

Comment: @Jaider: Some ideas: Check that all references to the files are using the correct filenames; Check that the file copies are not failing because they are trying to overwrite readable files, or trying to write to a folder that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the missing files to source control solved the problem for me.

Comment: Me too. For me, I was upgrading a script file (debug version & minified version). Both versions were shown in solution explorer and even included in my `.csproj` file, but for some reason the minified script was not added to source control. I "added existing item" to get the minified script and the problem went away.