# How to find where this file is being referenced, and why doesn't it find it?

Tags: tfs, build

I can't seem to get past the following error when building my project (from TFS Build Server). The project actually does not even need this file. It is definitely in the project in the location specified. I have tried deleting it from the project, and I have tried adding it back, yet it makes no difference.

It builds fine locally and I can publish it just fine locally. I can't seem to figure out what in the world is causing this though as I'm not aware of anything other than my project file referencing this just as a matter of it being included in the project and even when I removed it from the project (as mentioned above) there was apparently still some other place that it's getting referenced from and I have no clue where (and, again, no clue why it can't find it in the location it says it should be... which as far as I can tell is where it is).

I know I've run into this issue (or similar) before like when there are conflicting changes but I just can't seem to remember how I resolved it in the past.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Scripts\jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" because it was not found.
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Scripts\jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" because it was not found.

EDIT: I have created a new workspace and got the latest to verify that when I do this, I do in fact get the file in question. I think when I've faced this issue in the past that this test would have failed so I really don't know what the problem is this time. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS Build fails with "Could not copy file" of file not even in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623667/tfs-build-fails-with-could-not-copy-file-of-file-not-even-in-the-project) (BTW, the second sentence in your second paragraph is the longest run-on sentence I've ever seen, I believe. Can you read that in one go without breaking anywhere to take a breath?)

Comment: The trick is to breathe at the parentheticals ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was looking at the wrong project in the solution. Changes had not been made to that project as far I knew and the error (as seen in my post) did not indicate which project was the problem.

How I finally figured it out was I updated the build to clean the sources and output directory when building and then the error message I received actually included the project in the error.